# Material Design - stepper how to remove/disable steps?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

I'm using [Material - Angular2 Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview), and I have additional steps that I want to add/enable depending on what the user selects in the first step.

I tried the following:
- Load the additional forms into an array,
- then loop through it in the template with `*ngFor`

```
<mat-vertical-stepper linear>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstForm" label="First">
    <!-- Some form controls -->
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step *ngFor="let f of additionalForms" [stepControl]="f.form"
      [label]="f.label">
    <!-- Additional Steps -->
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

This works well for adding new steps, the problem is I can't remove them. If the user happened to come back to first form, and uncheck something, these additional steps wouldn't be required.

So trying something like: `this.additionalForms = []` doesn't remove the steps. (until you click on one of the "removed" steps, then it throws an error: `Cannot read property 'editable' of undefined`, and only then, they're removed visually)

I also tried doing `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`
and tried wrapping into the `NgZone.run()`

but made no difference

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I managed with this work-around:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7700#issuecomment-336138411

1) Make a reference to the stepper:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper></mat-vertical-stepper>
```

2) Then, on the .ts side:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatVerticalStepper } from '@angular/material';

@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatVerticalStepper;

clearAdditionalForms(): void {
  this.inventoryForms = [];
  this.stepper._stateChanged(); // <- this : Marks the component to be change detected.
}
```

This is calling a private method which is probably a really bad idea, so if you have a better/correct solution, let me know, and I'll change the answer

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more angular way, avoiding the private method way is to record what you need to do on the form control used by the step. So for instance let's say we have a step:

```
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
       <!-- your controls here -->
    </form>
  </mat-step>
```

Then define your form group:

```
this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  check: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
});
```

We have now defined a pseudo element "check", that will be validated by the step.
Let's say we set something with a click function:

```
  doClick(item) {
     this.secondFormGroup.controls.check.setValue(item === 'thevalue');     
  }
```

Angular material will now do the rest, you will not be able to move past the step until item === thevalue.

Answer (score 2):

Add *ngIf in each step

```
<mat-step *ngIf="*expression*"></mat-step>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, If you want to do not return the privously, you can use `stepper's` `editable` property as below

```
<mat-vertical-stepper linear>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstForm" label="First" [editable]="false">
    <!-- Some form controls -->
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step *ngFor="let f of additionalForms" [stepControl]="f.form"
      [label]="f.label">
    <!-- Additional Steps -->
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

based on https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#editable-step

Answer (score 0):

**Angular Material 8.2.3**

Best would be a [disabled] option, but incredibly they didn't add! So I tried all and I ended up a clean way to customize the step-headers:

To **show/hide** a step of course simply use *ngIf (what else?).

To **disable** steps dynamically based on user clicks / state of the store:

*With great results: no hover background effect, cursor is normal, single step-header unclickable, still looks with full color: not opaque.*

```js
steps: Array<HTMLElement> = [];
subscriptions: Array<Subscription> = [];

ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Needs continuous monitoring
    this.subscriptions.push(
        this.<observable>.pipe(
            tap((data: Data) => {
                // IMPORTANT: If you have an *ngIf on the steps,
                // you have to sync the references of the HTML elements
                this.syncHTMLSteps();
                this.updateStepState(1, false); // Always disabled
                if (data.isXXX) {
                    this.updateStepState(5, false);
                } else if (data.isYYY) {
                    this.updateStepState(2, false);
                    this.updateStepState(5, true);
                }
            })
        ).subscribe());
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => {
        if (subscription) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Reads from the Dom the list of HTML elements for the steps.
 */
private syncHTMLSteps() {
    this.steps = [];
    let increment = 1;
    let stepper: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.mat-stepper-vertical');
    if (!stepper) {
        increment = 2; // 2, because Angular adds 2 elements for each horizontal step
        stepper = document.querySelector('.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container');
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < stepper.children.length; i += increment) {
        this.steps.push(stepper.children[i] as HTMLElement);
    }

}

/**
 * Enable/Disable the click on the step header.
 *
 * @param step The step number (starts from 1)
 * @param enabled The new state
 */
private updateStepState(step: number, enabled: boolean) {
    // If you prefer to start using step 0, remove -1 here
    this.steps[step - 1].style.pointerEvents = enabled ? '' : 'none';
}
```